# Flexbox does not vertically center div inside table cell

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is the red div not centered vertically?

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/aWWgBK?editors=1000

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black" class="table">
  <thead>

    <th>selected</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="align-middle"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <div style="background:red;"> this text should be vertically aligned in the center of the table cell </div>

      </td>
      <td class="align-middle">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Abbrechen</button>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
          <li>item 5</li>
          <li>item 6</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you change the `display` value of a table cell from `table-cell` to `flex`, it appears to mess up the table algorithm.

But to vertically center the content of a table-cell, you just need `vertical-align: middle`. (It's one of those rare instances when [this stubborn property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align?v=example) actually works – on table-cell and inline elements.)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wddVPy?editors=1000

Comment: I need the flexbox still for some divs inside the table cell but using the vertical-align:middle on the outer cell and using flexbox in the inside stuff works for me :-)

Comment: I think I tried 5-6 different variations of flex (on Chrome). Nothing worked. So I just went old-school :-)